# Videos handled by multer have no sound

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, multer

I'm using multer in node.js to handle when users upload videos to my site, and it was working fine initially, which is why i'm so confused. Now the video uploaded has no sound.

here's the upload form

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
    <title>Video Upload</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <h1>Video Upload</h1> 

    <form action="http://localhost:80/upload" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> 


    <br>Video Title  <input type="text" name="title" required/><br>
    <br>
        <input type="file" name="video" required/> <br> 
        <br>


        <input type="submit" value="submit">  
    </form> 
</body> 

</html>
```

and here's the relevant backend code, with multer i also used ffmetadata to save the title of the video, and uuid/v4 for the filename.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, __dirname + "/videos")
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, uuid() + ".mp4")
    }
})



//max file size -- 500mb
const maxSize = 524288000;

var upload = multer({
storage: storage,
limits: {fileSize: maxSize},
fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
var filetypes = /mp4/
var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype)
console.log(file)
var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()); 
if(mimetype && extname){
    return cb(null, true)
}

//err 
cb("Error: File upload only supports the " + "following filetypes - " + filetypes); 
}

}).single("video")

app.get("/upload", function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/upload.html")
})

app.post("/upload", function(req, res){
    upload(req, res, function(err){
        console.log(req.body.title)
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        }
        else{
            metaData.write(req.file.path, {title: req.body.title}, function(err){
                if(err){

                    res.send(err)
                }
                else{
                    res.send("uploaded")
                }
            })

        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I have further tested the code, and found out its the metaData package giving me problems, so now it only gives me the audio instead of the video.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my problem by switching from req.file.path to req.file.filename